# Other meanings of "cage"

Tags: meaning

I know that cages are used to lock people or animals up. But what is the meaning when we are talking about the healthcare industry? I saw this word in a presentation of a company that sells surgical equipment. The sentence was: "if you buy our cage, you buy our biologic".

Comment: More context please.  I don't know what "biologic" it, as it likely has a specific meaning related to the surgical equipment or its use.

Comment: I guess they might have misspelled the word, I think they meant "biology". they sell equipment that is implanted in people during surgeries and also organic materials like bone tissue.

Comment: No, I think "biologic" makes sense when talking about implanted chips and things.  It's jargon composed of "bio-" (which implies the organic stuff) and "logic" (which implies the technology stuff).  I just don't know how it relates to "cage" since that might also be jargon.

Answer (score 1):

The word cage has a specific meaning in spinal surgury.

Your spine has bones (called vertebrae) separated by discs. If the discs become damaged, the bones will rub against each other causing back pain.

One solution to this is to insert a hollow screw with holes in the side between the vertebrae. This holds the vertebrae apart, in the correct position. The hollow screw is called a "cage". The body will grow new bone through and around the cage, joining the two vertebrae together.

Further discussion, and images can be found at [Houston Methodist](http://www.houstonmethodist.org/orthopedics/where-does-it-hurt/lower-back/anterior-lumbar-fusion-with-cages/)

A biologic is a drug or medicine that is made from biological sources instead of being synthesised chemically. Insulin is a biologic, Asprin is not. Biologics are also called "[biopharmaceuticals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biopharmaceutical)". Bone graft is type of biologic, and the gaps formed between the cage and the vertebrae can be called "biologic void".

Comment: The area where the cage is placed is called a biologic void.